# Is there any possibility to rebuild templates in utask (ovh/utask) on runtime?

Tags: go, workflow, ovh, workflow-engine

I want to use ovh/utask as workflow engine in my app: https://github.com/ovh/utask

I want to allow customer to create templates in my primary app and save them as workflows. Parsed Yaml files will be saved into git ignored directory inside templates/customer.

After restarting docker container I can see all templates.

Is there any option to rebuild templates in runtime without restarting it?

I checked Utask github documentation, and all api endpoints provided in service (Swagger)